# PNG Saves As Larger Size In Photoshop

Tags: photoshop

I have a search icon at 2kb. I open in Photoshop, reduce it's dimensions to half, and the size comes out as 4kb.

Any idea what I can do to reduce the size when saving and reducing the dimensions? Not sure what's causing this.

Thank you!

Comment: up the compression level, or reduce the detail. could be you've removed enough repeating detail that the "smaller" file actually HAS to be larger.

Comment: I think this question belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or maybe [Photography Stack Exchange](http://photo.stackexchange.com/). On either of which they will probably suggest using "Save for web and devices..." to avoid PS saving metadata in the .png.

Comment: Hey, that isn't a programming question, but regardless, Photoshop is terrible at saving out small PNG files. See for yourself. If you really want to reduce the filesize take a look at [PNGCrush](http://pngcrush.com) instead

Answer (score 0):

When object is a vector it cost low space in the photoshopfile.

you can use png8 instead of png24 to save a lot of bytes